# No internet connection, mail app works

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have just solved the Bad Pool Caller/Header BSOD bug (after corrupt Kaspersky installation). At the same time when the BSODs started to pop up my internet connection stopped working. I use WiFi and it displays that the connection is working.

No web browsers can display pages. Chrome suggests changing the proxy settings (they are at default). Metro apps don't work either (but the mail app is working just fine - at least the gmail account).

I made a disk check and it found and fixed 1 error. I performed a clean boot (but I'm not sure if I did it correctly).

Answer (score 1):

What errors are being displayed when you attempt to browse a website?

Since you are using an HTTP Mail app like Gmail then that rules out a problem with your computer being able to send and receive HTTP traffic, it also rules out any issues with your internet connection.  Especially seeing as how you said your network settings say the wireless network is functioning correctly.

That means that you you are having an error that has something to do with your web browser specifically.  I could go into more depth and do some research on what exactly may be causing it but to be honest the easiest thing to do first in order to rule out browser issues is to first try using Internet Explorer and or Firefox or some other browser.  If that works then you have a specific issue with Chrome and I would recommend you un-install it and re-install it.

If none of you're browsers are working then we can move on from there. Comment and let me know if you have done this yet and I will try and help you figure out a solution.

Comment: I tried this with MS IE, Chrome and Firefox. They all display the standard message about the inability to load the page (check if the address is correct etc.) Also every single internet accessing application cannot access it (inlcuding Windows 8 Store, News, MS Outlook). Only the Mail app works (I have no idea why). I have numerous programs which use the internet connection in some way but they all dont work. Im sure that this isnt the case of the browser or any other app. There is something specific with windows settings. Also I tried disabling the windows wall and it didnt solve the problem.

Comment: Reboot the System into Safemode with networking and try to access the internet.  If that works do a Cleanboot following these instructions: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135

Comment: Too boot into safe mode follow these instructions: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode

Comment: Found someone with a similar issue here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_store/some-windows-8-apps-wont-connect-to-the-internet/89fcf746-f034-4445-aec8-211868b390db

Comment: And here is someone else but the answer appears to be somewhat the same, maybe it can help.  Try to do what they said which starts with the cleanboot like I said before and let me know if you still can't get it fixed.  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/windows-8-apps-no-internet-connection/09c89430-eabf-4d67-b56a-4e22662f26a7

Comment: Also try to disable your proxy just in case: Disable Proxy Settings
If you are using any Proxy connection, then try disabling the proxy connection and check.
    Check if proxy server settings are enabled. To do this, try these           steps:
    a. Disable proxy server on Internet Explorer (IE)
    b. Press the ‘Windows + R’ key on the keyboard.
    x. In the ‘Run’ type inetcpl.cpl and hit enter.                        
    d. Click Connections tab, click LAN settings button.
    e. Uncheck "Use a proxy server for your LAN" under proxy server.f. Click ok to apply the changes.

Comment: Sorry I can't figure out this text formatting for the life of me...

Comment: OK, the safe boot with networking solves the problem. How can I revert the settings to the standard boot?

Comment: Follow the directions for the Cleanboot  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135

Comment: I made this clean boot a couple of times (with different settings). There must be a Microsoft service causing the problem. In Safe Mode with networking everything works.

Comment: So after the Cleanboot it still isn't working?

Comment: First try to completely disable your firewall.  Also can you post an `ipconfig /all` while in normal mode and another one while in safe mode?  To do this go to a command prompt and simply type `ipconfig /all`  Here is a link on disabling the firewall.  http://windows8themes.org/networking-how-to-disable-firewall-in-windows-8.html

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I had to enter the settings of my wifi connection and turn off Comodo Agent or something. It caused all the problems. IPV6 wasnt working.

Thank you for your effort in solving it.